# How does IDN look in browser address bar

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, idn

I want to buy IDN domain but I am not sure how is's going to look in a browser. Like, will users see `xn-` part or it will look just as normal in my language ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related. It might be suitable for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Here's the reference for Chrome https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/idn-in-google-chrome and Firefox https://wiki.mozilla.org/IDN_Display_Algorithm#Algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a handy explanation for you on how it works: https://www.name.com/idn

Essentially any non-local user whose system doesn't support your language will see xn- url, but any user whose system has that language installed will see appropriately converted url.